# ListView Android prints the same items many time

Tags: android, listview

Adapter

```
import ...;
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        MyObject myobj = getItem(position);
        String objectName = myobj.getName();

        TextView name_TV = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name_TV.setText(objectName);
        return view1; 
    } 
}
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList <MyObject> obj_list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    obj_list.add(new MyObject("user1", 123));
    obj_list.add(new MyObject("user2", 123));
    obj_list.add(new MyObject("user3", 123));

    CustomAdapter adptr = new CustomerAdapter(this, obj_list);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.abcListview);
    lv.setAdapter(adptr);
}
```

MyObject class

```
public class MyObject{
     String a;
     int b;
     public MyObject(String a, int b){
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b; 
     }
     public String getName(){
         return a;
     }
}
```

The code will make 3 list view items and print the "user3" three times instead of printing "user1" one time, "user2" one time, "user3" one time.

**Edit**
result of the code above: http://imgur.com/BBJS0wt

Comment: (1) Please use RecyclerView (2) If you refuse to use RecyclerView at least make use of convertView parameter (3) Post code of MyObject class

Comment: @GregEnnis I added the code of MyObject class. I am new to android programming, I do not know what RecyclerView is

Comment: Try to create and set the CustomAdapter adptr, before you add objects to the ArrayList. Then add your objects to your ArrayList and use lv.notifyDataSetChanged(). 

And see if it does the same thing.

Comment: @RobertSimoes tried it, but it does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

> You should use the `ViewHolder` paradigm.

**EDITED**

The problem is in your `getView()`, Try this:

```
public static class ViewHolder {

 public TextView name;

}
MyObject myobj;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View view1 = convertView;
   ViewHolder holder;

  if (null == view1) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, null);

    holder.name = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.name);

    view1.setTag(holder);

   }
   else
    holder = (ViewHolder) view1.getTag();

    myobj = getItem(position);
    if (myobj == null)
        return view1;

    String objectName = myobj.getName();
     holder.name.setText(objectName);

   return view1; 

}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I guess the 'return view1' should be after the else bracket. With your code I am the result I am getting is: "user3" , "New text", "New text". ("New text" is the default value)

Comment: But I would like to suggest you using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. Look at this for more info [Getting Started With RecyclerView and CardView on Android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)